# jekyll does not work in my windows 7

Tags: jekyll, static-site

I have installed jekyll in my windows 7, but it does not work. I have created a folder called jekyllSite and have included the necessary files in the folder, then I open Command Prompt and and `cd` in that folder and run `jekyll` code. It generates the following message. I can not understand what is wrong?

```
←[1mNAME←[0m:

    jekyll

  ←[1mDESCRIPTION←[0m:

    Jekyll is a blog-aware, static site generator in Ruby

  ←[1mCOMMANDS←[0m:

    build                Build your site
    default
    docs                 Launch local server with docs for Jekyll v1.2.1

    doctor               Search site and print specific deprecation
warnings
    help                 Display global or [command] help documentation.

    import               Import your old blog to Jekyll
    new                  Creates a new Jekyll site scaffold in PATH

    serve                Serve your site locally

  ←[1mALIASES←[0m:

    hyde                 doctor
    server               serve

  ←[1mGLOBAL OPTIONS←[0m:

    -s, --source [DIR]
        Source directory (defaults to ./)

    -d, --destination [DIR]
        Destination directory (defaults to ./_site)

    --safe
        Safe mode (defaults to false)

    -p, --plugins PLUGINS_DIR1[,PLUGINS_DIR2[,...]]
        Plugins directory (defaults to ./_plugins)

    --layouts DIR
        Layouts directory (defaults to ./_layouts)

    -h, --help
        Display help documentation

    -v, --version
        Display version information

    -t, --trace
        Display backtrace when an error occurs
```

Comment: Well? Did you run it with any of the command line parameters that it tells you about?

Comment: I can not understand you. I only cd in the folder and run jekyll code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output you've provided is just a description of what jekyll executables can do. To have any results you should use jekyll command either to build the site (to prepare static files instantly) or to host the site.

So, in those cases you just either use:

```
jekyll build
```

or

```
jekyll serve
```

respectively.

Comment: Well, frankly saying your question tells that you might just be a bit not fully sure how jekyll basicly works, so I would recommend to read just a bit more of documentation. (Even though, jekyll was really not born for Windows, its basics are pretty simple even on this platform).